# Adding items to NSMutableArray doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm taking the lectures of [Stanford's iPhone application development](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall) and the first assignment is to build a RPN calculator.

I'm having an issue that is probably something simple that I'm missing out.

There is a model class, called CalculatorBrain:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject

- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand;
- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain()

@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain

@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;

- (NSMutableArray *)operandStack
{
    if (!_operandStack) {
        _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return _operandStack;
}

- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
    [self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];
}

- (double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if (operandObject) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}

@end
```

And there's the controller class, CalculatorViewController:
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    NSString *currentDisplayText = self.display.text;

    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        self.display.text = [currentDisplayText stringByAppendingString:digit];
    }
    else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed {
    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];

    NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long) [self.brain.operandStack count]);
    NSLog(@"index 0: %@", [self.brain.operandStack objectAtIndex:0]);
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
}

@end
```

The problem is in the enterPressed method. As you can see, I put 2 NSLog lines to see if the numbers are being pushed into the array, but they're not. The two lines return me 0 and null.
I know I don't need to use @synthesize anymore(in the CalculatorBrain class) but I've tried with and without it, and the items are not being added anyway.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: The lazy creation of the NSMutableArray in that getter is quite non-standard.  Better to create it in your initializer, which also serves to eliminate the custom getter/setter entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@synthesize` only creates the setters and getters for the property. They are default in modern Objective-C. But `@syntehsize` doesn't initialize the object and assign it by itself. So you still have to initialize `brain`. The default value is `nil`. So unless you assign a new object to it, it will stay `nil`. That's why you were getting these values.

You can do that in `- viewDidLoad`

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: The initialization was in the walkthrough document for assignment 1.  Page 199.  They have you lazy initializing.

Comment: Woops, guess I missed that for some reason, thanks (:

Answer (score 2):

Almost for sure `self.brain` is nil - try logging it too.